# Multithreaded http/https Man in the middle Proxy, Socket Performance

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, sockets, proxy

Question edited following first comment.

My problem is mostly with java socket performance, and especially reading from the target server.

The server is a simple serversocket.accept() loop that create a client thread for every connection from firefox

Main problem is socket input stream reading that blocks for enormous amounts of time.

Client thread is as follows :

```
//Take an httpRequest (hc.apache.org), raw string http request, and the firefox socket outputstream 
private void handle(httpRequest req, String raw, Outputstream out)
{

        InputStream targetIn =null;
        OutputStream targetOut = null;
        Socket target = null;

        try {
        System.out.println("HANDLE HTTP");
            String host = req.getHeaders("Host")[0].getValue();
            URI uri = new URI(req.getRequestLine().getUri());
            int port = uri.getPort() != -1 ? uri.getPort() : 80;
            target = new Socket(host, port);


//**I have tried to play around with these but cannot seem to get a difference in performance**

            target.setTcpNoDelay(true);
//          target.setReceiveBufferSize(1024 *1024);
//          target.setSendBufferSize(1024 * 1024);


//Get your plain old in/out streams         
            targetIn = target.getInputStream();
            targetOut = target.getOutputStream();

//Send the request to the target
            System.out.println("---------------Start response---------------");
            targetOut.write(raw.getBytes());
            System.out.println("request sent to target");

        ////Same as membrane            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int length = 0;
            try {
                while((length = targetIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    out.flush();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("closing out + target socket");


//IOUTILS
//          long count = IOUtils.copyLarge(targetIn, out, 0L, 1048576L);
//          int count = IOUtils.copy(targetIn, out);
//          System.out.println("transfered : " + count );


//CHANNEL COPY
//
//          ReadableByteChannel input = Channels.newChannel(targetIn);
//          WritableByteChannel output = Channels.newChannel(out);
//          
//          ChannelTools.fastChannelCopy(input, output);
//          
//          input.close();
//          output.close();


//CHAR TO CHAR COPY         
//            int c;
//            while ((c = targetIn.read()) != -1) {
//                out.write(c);
//            }


            target.close();
            out.close();

            System.out.println("--------------------  end response   ------------------------------");
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The main problem lies in in the appropriate method to copy the target inputstream to the client (firefox) outputstream.

The site i am using to test this out is http://www.ouest-france.fr (new site with a load of images and makes loads of requests).

Ping time from workstation to target : 10ms

Normal Loading in iceweasel (debian firefox, firebug time) : 14 secs, 2.5MB

Loading behind this proxy : 14 minutes (firebug net panel is full of fake 404s, and aborted request that go back to black after a certain time, loads of requests are in blocking or waiting mode)

Now when executing i loadup visual vm, launch profiling with no class filter (to see where the app is really spending its time) and it spends 99% of its time in java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int), which is reading on the target socket input stream.

I think i have done my homework and been searching a testing different solutions juste about anywhere i could.

but performance never seems to improve.

I What i have already tried :

-Putting input and output streams into their buffered version, no change at all

-int to int copy, no change at all,

-classic byte[] array copy with variable sized arrays, no change at all

fiddling around with settcpnodelay, setsendbuffersize, setreceivebuffersize, could not get any change.

Was thinking of trying out nio socketchannels , but cannot find a way to do the socket to sslsocket hijacking.

So at the moment i am a bit stuck and searching for solutions.

I look at the source code of open sources proxies and cannot seem to find a fundamental difference in logic so i am completely lost with this.

Tried a other test :

export http_proxy="localhost:4242"
wget debiandvd.iso

Throughput gets to 2MB/s.
And threads seems to spend 66% time reading from target an 33% time writing to client

I am thinking that maybe i have to many threads running but running a test on www.google.com has much less requests going through but still the sames problems as www.ouest-france.fr

With the debian iso test i was thinking i had to many threads running (ouest-france is around 270 requests) but the google test (10 request) test seems to confirm that thread numbers are not the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Environment is debian, sun java 1.6, dev with eclipse and visualvm

I can provide the rest of the code as needed.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry but this question is just too long.  Please edit it to whittle it down to some succinct questions.  As it stands it is just too long and too rambling.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution found :

Not a very clean solution but works.

I still have a throughput problem.

What I do is set the socket timer to a normal timeout (30000ms).

When the first read has come in the loop I reset the timer to something a lot lower (1000ms at the moment).

That allows me to wait for the server to start sending data, and if I get 1 second without any new data coming I consider the transfer to be finished.

Response times are still quite slow but way better.